# argument Where of type xxxxxx is required, but it was not provided

Tags: apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I have this strange issue . maybe i missed something

i have two tables , Vehicles and purchases

when i try to query the vehicles via

```
    query {
                vehicles{
          id
        }
    }
```

It returns data normally

```
{
  "data": {
    "vehicles": [
      {
        "id": 29
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But with this query

```
    query {
                purchase{
          id
        }
    }
```

I recieve this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Field \"purchase\" argument \"where\" of type \"purchaseWhereUniqueInput!\" is required, but it was not provided.",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3
          }
        ],
```

here is my code : -

```
export const PaymentQuery =extendType({
  type :"Query",
  definition(t) {
    t.crud.purchase({filtering : true , pagination : true , ordering : true , })
  }
})

export const VehicleQuery = extendType({
  type : "Query",
  definition(t) {
    t.crud.vehicles({filtering : true , pagination : true , ordering : true , });
  }
})
```

Comment: It's a spelling mistake. Should be `t.crud.purchases()`

Answer (score 0):

I realized that nexusjs use naming convention to determine if the query should return a list or not !

changing the table name from `purchase` to `purchases` solves the problem